# Return values of two tags which has same name, in an array

Tags: xml, perl, xml-libxml

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<CONFIG>
  <item>
    <phone>1234578</phone>
    <phone>876543321</phone>
   </item>
</CONFIG>
```

I need to get both the numbers in an array with 2 elements.

My Perl code:

```
my $xmlDoc = XML::LibXML->new->parse_file($config_file);
$Xpath = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new($xmlDoc);

my @item = $Xpath->findnodes('/CONFIG/item');
my $phone = $item[0]->findvalue('/CONFIG/item/phone');
print $phone
```

output:

```
1234578876543321
```

`$phone` contains a single string with both the numbers concatenated as a single entity

I even tried with returning to array context, it still returns one element with both numbers concatenated

Can you please help me get these two phone numbers separately?

Answer (score 2):

I'm unclear why you think you had to involve `XML::LibXML::XPathContext` as there are no namespaces in the XML data that you show

Your call

```
my @item = $Xpath->findnodes('/CONFIG/item');
```

returns a single `XML::LibXML::Element` object in array `@items` because there is only one `/CONFIG/item` node. But then your call

```
my $phone = $item[0]->findvalue('/CONFIG/item/phone');
```

ignores the context of that node because you have specified an absolute XPath expression. It rescans the document looking for all `/CONFIG/item/phone` elements and concatenates their text values, giving `1234578876543321` as you have seen

I have found `find` and `findvalue` to be badly-implemented in this Perl module, and always rely on `findnodes`, which makes things very simple

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use XML::LibXML;

my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => 'CONFIG.xml');

print $_->textContent, "\n" for $dom->findnodes('/CONFIG/item/phone');
```

#### output

```
1234578
876543321
```

If you need those values in an array, then just use `map`

```
my @phones = map { $_->textContent } $dom->findnodes('/CONFIG/item/phone');
```